# Java Servlet: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.parser.ParseException

Tags: java, android, servlets, push-notification

I am implementing Google Cloud Messaging service for android. I have created a test server which sends push notifications to application users. But the server I have created is generating following error. I am using Java Servlet at server side and have included gcm-server.jar file in project.

I tried with following jar files
1. json-simple-1.1.jar
2. json-simple-1.1.1.jar
Even though getting the same error.

here is the error report

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet HelloWorld threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.parser.ParseException
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
at com.GCM.servlets.HelloWorld.SendMessage(HelloWorld.java:48)
at com.GCM.servlets.HelloWorld.doPost(HelloWorld.java:41)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The json-simple-1.1.jar should appear in the WEB-INF/lib folder of your web application deployed into Tomcat. See http://java.sun.com/j2ee/verified/packaging.html#mechs .

Comment: Thanks Dan Gravell. it works fine...

Comment: It saying it requires 15 reputation :)

Comment: @DanGravell +1...you got another...:)

Comment: Dammn, I just spent 3 hours in knowing this.

Answer (score 0):

json-simple-1.1.jar was in my classpath twice. Removed one instance and problem fixed.